# ¿Como actualizar las variables de openBuilder en un OpenContainer desde el widget padre, una vez que ya fue abierto?

Tags: flutter, dart

llevo con este problema ya mucho tiempo y no he encontrado la manera de solucionarlo.
Tengo una pantalla que muestra una lista de días trabajados de un empleado, en la lista se muestra poca información sobre el día, pero se actualiza en tiempo real, al tocar un elemento de la lista, se debe abrir una pantallla donde muestre toda la informacion sobre el dia y que igualmente se actualize en tiempo real.

**Widget padre**

```dart
OpenContainer(
      closedBuilder: (context, openContainer) {
        // Esto es lo que se muestra en la lista
        return Text(dbdata);
      },
      openBuilder: (context, openContainer) {
        // Esto es lo que se muestra al abrir un dia
        return ChildWidget(data: dbdata);
      },
    );
```

la variable **dbdata** se actualiza constantemente a travez de un StreamSubscription

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    myStream.listen((d) {
      setState(() {
        dbdata = d;
      });
    });
  }
```

y este es el widget que se abre en **openBuilder**

**Widget hijo**

```dart
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChildWidget({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);
  final String data;

  @override
  State<ChildWidget> createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(widget.data),
    );
  }
}
```

lo que se muestra en **closedBuilder** se actualiza correctamente cuando cambia el valor de **dbdata**, pero lo que esta en **openBuilder** ya no se actualiza, ya comprobé que la suscripción del stream siga funcionando cuando se abre el widget hijo y si lo hace, pero aunque se cambie el valor de la variable, el widget hijo sigue mostrando los mismos datos sin cambiar. y lo que no quiero es tener que crear otra StreamSubscription.

¿Que puedo hacer para solucionar esto?

Comment: está refrescando la variable, pero el widget ya fue abierto, el widget ha sido montado en otra ruta del navigator, no en la misma, por lo tanto el widget no refresca, podrías pasarle un stream al widget childwiget

Answer (score 0):

no utilizo statefull ya que soy de los de usar statemanagement como getx, pero por lo que veo el hijo también es un statefull y puede ser que el setState de arriba no lo tenga activo.
No acabo de ver la necesidad de este statefull ya que internamente no vas ha hacer nada para modificarlo. Ya te digo que a mi se me pierde un poco esto del statefull. Yo, si no te importa, probaria a poner como hijo del openBuilder el objetto hijo:

```
openBuilder: (context, openContainer) {
    // Esto es lo que se muestra al abrir un dia
    return Center(child: Text(data)),
  },
```

También puedes cambiar el widget hijo de una clase a un metodo helper dentro de la otra clase.

Yo es que, despues de ver el video sobre class vs helper method me quedo con los ultimos, salvo que yo tenga una necesidad concreta, como que el componente hijo tenga que ser diferente en cada momento, o sea, tenga variables propias.

Un consejo, no abuses de widgets como clases se lia un poco el tema....

Ya dirás....

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, lo puse exactamente igual que tu :c

Comment: Perdona no lo transcribas tal cual, donde pongo data tiene que ser dbdata, obviamente